# i want to display a Quadratic equation with format like (4x2)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

i want to display a Quadratic equation with format like (4x2). i want to display 2 as superscript automatically after typing x in the textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode offers superscript digits.

- `\u2070` = ⁰
- `\u00B9` = ¹
- `\u00B2` = ²
- `\u00B3` = ³
- `\u2074` = ⁴
- `\u2075` = ⁵
- `\u2076` = ⁶
- `\u2077` = ⁷
- `\u2078` = ⁸
- `\u2079` = ⁹

So simply replace a 2 that's supposed to be superscript with U+00B2.

```
4x² - 2x + 4
```

Here's some sample code:

```
private static const SUPER_DIGIT:Object = {
    '0':0x2070, '1':0x00B9, '2':0x00B2, '3':0x00B3, '4':0x2074, 
    '5':0x2075, '6':0x2076, '7':0x2077, '8':0x2078, '9':0x2079,
    '-':0x207B 
};

// Converts all 0123456789- characters to their superscript forms.
public static function toSuperscript(str:String):String {
    var buffer:Array = new Array(str.length);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        buffer[i] = SUPER_DIGIT[str.charAt(i)];
        if (buffer[i] == null) buffer[i] = str.charCodeAt(i); 
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buffer);
}
```

**Edit:**
If you passed my method `4x2` it'd return `⁴x²`.  What you need to do is--within an update event on your text field--detect substrings that need to be converted to superscript and replace them.  A quick rule that'll work for you is to say "if a digit comes immediately after a character with a code equal to or greater than 'A' (\u0041), replace it with its superscript equivillant."

Comment: i don't know how to link your code with dynamic text field. could you please mention about that?

Comment: @Pen: I added an explanation to the end of my answer.